# How to change plugin setting dynamically in CKEDITOR?

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, word-count

How can I manage to change a setting of a plugin dynamically when CKEDITOR instances are created?

I wrote in a custom config.js:

```
config.wordcount = {
    // Whether or not you want to show the Word Count
    showWordCount: false,
    // Whether or not you want to show the Char Count
    showCharCount: true
};
```

What I want to do is to set `maxCharCount` to something, depending on the CKEDITOR instance.

Is there an easy way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

Found the solution:

```
CKEDITOR.replace('field', {
    wordcount: {'showWordCount': false,
                'showParagraphs': false,
                'showCharCount': true,
                'maxCharCount': 100
            }
});
```

Comment: Thank you! saved me a bit of time

Comment: Hi Kaymaz, How can we add font size selector to CKEDITOR